# How to do some cleanup after the client closes the connection

Tags: scala, akka

I'm creating a proxy API using akka that does some preparations before forwarding the request to the actual API. For one of the endpoints, the response is streaming json data and the client may close the connection at any time. Akka seems to handle this automatically, but the issue is I need to do some cleanup after the client closes the connection.

```
path("query") {
  post {

    decodeRequest {
      entity(as[Query]) { query =>
        // proxy does some preparations
        val json: String = query.prepared.toJson.toString()

        // proxy sends request to actual server
        val request = HttpRequest(
          method = HttpMethods.POST,
          uri = serverUrl + "/query",
          entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/json`, json)
        )
        val responseFuture = Http().singleRequest(request)
        val response: HttpResponse = Await.result(responseFuture, PROXY_TIMEOUT)

        // proxy forwards server's response to user
        complete(response)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried doing something like

```
responseFuture.onComplete(_ => doCleanup())
```

But that doesn't work because responseFuture completes immediately even though the server continues to send data until the client closes the connection. complete(response) also returns immediately.

So I'm wondering how I can make a call to doCleanup() only after the client has closed the connection.

Edit: The cleanup I need to do is because the proxy creates some data streams that are meant to be temporary and only persist until the last message is sent by the server. Once that happens these streams need to be deleted.

Comment: Could you please explain what kind of cleanup you want to do? Most probably Http route is not the best place to perform it. Also connection is a low-level Tcp concern. Don't think you can/should deal with it in Http-level code.

Comment: Question updated

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with minimal changes to you code like that:

```
val responseFuture = Http().singleRequest(request)
val response: HttpResponse = try {
                               Await.result(responseFuture, PROXY_TIMEOUT)
                             } finally {
                                 doCleanup()
                             }

complete(response)
```

or you can do it without blocking:

```
val responseFuture = Http().singleRequest(request)
val cleaned = responseFuture.andThen{case _  => doCleanUp()}
complete(cleaned) //it's possible to complete response with Future
```